# Alternative to agent ransack on the macintosh?

Tags: macos, mac

When i was on windows I would use a software called agent ransack , that lets me look for a string within hundreds of files. On the mac what similar apps exists that you know of?

thanks

Comment: A new alternative for Mac is [File Content Finder](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/file-content-finder/id1448621435) app on the [app store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/file-content-finder/9mzc4sk6j6bp) (**disclaimer** - I'm its developer). It's can search for searching file contents without indexing. All major file formats are supported - pdf, doc(x), xls(x), rtf, pptx, and others. It can even search scanned documents.

Answer (score 4):

Like on most UNIX-based systems, `grep` is always your friend.

Answer (score 2):

The spotlight search in finder can search inside files.  But I agree that grep is the best tool for the job.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of spotlight! +1